# tikz figure (vigenere square) behaves strangely in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am writing a macro to produce Vigenere squares in tikz. It is a square plus a cross overlapping it which highlight the letter which is changed. The code is the following.

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\documentclass{standalone}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\vigenerecross}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,transform shape]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,25} {
      \foreach \j in {0,...,25} {
        \edef\k{\ifnum\numexpr\i+\j\relax>25
          \the\numexpr\i+\j-26\relax
          \else
          \the\numexpr\i+\j\relax
        \fi}
        \ifnum\i=\numexpr`#2-`A\relax
         \ifnum\j=\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red, minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.6,-\j*0.6) {\color{black}\strut\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \else
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red!20!white, minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.6,-\j*0.6) {\color{black}\strut\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \fi
        \else
         \ifnum\j=\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red!20!white, minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.6,-\j*0.6) {\color{black}\strut\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \fi
        \fi
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newsavebox{\vigeneresquare}
\savebox{\vigeneresquare}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,transform shape]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,25} {
      \foreach \j in {0,...,25} {
        \edef\k{\ifnum\numexpr\i+\j\relax>25
          \the\numexpr\i+\j-26\relax
          \else
          \the\numexpr\i+\j\relax
        \fi}
        \node[draw, minimum size=0.6cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.6,-\j*0.6) {\color{black}\strut\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\vigenere}[2]{{\usebox{\vigeneresquare}\llap{\vigenerecross{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\vigenere{M}{L}
\end{document}
```

It works nicely but if I insert it in a beamer file (just uncomment the first two lines and comment the third) then the output is wrong: the overlapping cross is somewhat smaller and out of sync.

Why does this happen? How to fix it?

PS: I used this somewhat strange idea instead of highlighting directly inside the square the relevant letters because if I use it many (many) times to produce a sort of animation of the enciphering process then this way it compiles really quicker.

Comment: ,@brad  - Since you did it right in a `standalone` picture, why don't you just insert the output picture using the `overlay` option of `tikz` or directly using the `\includegraphics`? This way, you will avoid `beamer` problems plus gaining speed by not compiling the picture every time you compile your file.

Comment: Wrap `\vigenere{M}{L}` inside `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}`

Comment: @AboAmmar: Yes, that would be a workaround but I would like to understand why latex does so (I also would like to have a standalone document, but that's not vital)

Comment: @samcarter: Since the result doesn't change (I checked before posting) I didn't put it in a frame to make the example as simple as possible. posting

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I eventually was able to solve my problem.

In case it can be of any interest for anybody, I post the solution (at least, what I have worked out).

The code which behaves correctly is as follows:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
\documentclass{standalone}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\vigenerecross}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,transform shape]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,25} {
      \foreach \j in {0,...,25} {
        \edef\k{\ifnum\numexpr\i+\j\relax>25
          \the\numexpr\i+\j-26\relax
          \else
          \the\numexpr\i+\j\relax
        \fi}
        \ifnum\i=\numexpr`#2-`A\relax
         \ifnum\j=\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red, minimum size=0.9cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.9,-\j*0.9) {\normalsize\color{black}\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \else
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red!20!white, minimum size=0.9cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.9,-\j*0.9) {\normalsize\color{black}\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \fi
        \else
         \ifnum\j=\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
          \node[draw, color=green, fill=red!20!white, minimum size=0.9cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.9,-\j*0.9) {\normalsize\color{black}\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
         \fi
        \fi
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newsavebox{\vigeneresquare}
\savebox{\vigeneresquare}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,transform shape]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,25} {
      \foreach \j in {0,...,25} {
        \edef\k{\ifnum\numexpr\i+\j\relax>25
          \the\numexpr\i+\j-26\relax
          \else
          \the\numexpr\i+\j\relax
        \fi}
        \node[draw, minimum size=0.9cm,inner sep=0pt] at (\i*0.9,-\j*0.9) {\normalsize\color{black}\symbol{\numexpr`A+\k\relax}};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\vigenere}[2]{{\usebox{\vigeneresquare}\llap{\vigenerecross{#1}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
  \vigenere{F}{G}
\end{document}
```

Comments:

- the shift of the cross is removed adding a % after `\end{tikzpicture}` (I still can't understand why, but this is it)
- letters inside every box are correctly centered removing `\strut` (this sounds reasonable)
- `size=0.9cm` gives better proportions and fix horizontal lines which where not correct (this also sounds reasonable)
- `\normalsize` assures that letters have the same dimension both in the square and in the cross, which was not the case in beamer class without it (I guess this is because the square is saved with `\savebox` in the preamble whereas the cross is computed on the fly inside the document, where I assume some different settings are used for the fonts)

Comment: As an explanation for the % after `\end{tikzpicture}`: https://tug.org/tug2015/abstracts/gregorio.txt